# Parameter based on SP is missing a value SSRS Visual Studio 2015

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

1- I have a shared dataset that gets style properties from SQL server by calling a stored procedure. These are, for example, a field with an array of color codes.

2- I load the shared dataset within a dataset embedded in my report ("use a shared dataset").

3- I create a hidden parameter "color" which available values are set to None; Default values are set to "Get values from a query" and value field is set to the color array in question.

When I run the report, I get the "parameter is missing a value" exception. What's weird is that I have another report running the same settings that works perfectly fine.

Any tips?

Comment: So there are no values to choose from but you want to set a default? I think you need to switch them around.

Comment: Hi Snowlockk thanks for your reply. The parameter is hidden so you don't need Available Values, as I have read on other SO entries on this topic.

Comment: ok but try it atleast.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have both the Available Values and Default Values pointed to the query. Also check the "Allow multiple values" setting in your parameter properties. Depending on how you're using the parameter values throughout the report, you may need to make use of the `Join` and `Split` functions to pull out the individual values from the array, but that would be a separate issue.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for your suggestion. I keep getting the same exception even when I point the Available Values to the query. This is weird because as I mentioned, I have another report using the same stored procedure, query and parameter settings (without Available Values and with the Default values pointing to the query) that works fine. I am indeed using Split to separate the values from the array.